# CodeIgniter routes: I keep getting a 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a application/controller/login.php file containing the following

```
class Login extends Controller {

  function Login()
  {
    parent::Controller();  
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->mysmarty->assign('title', 'Login');
    $this->mysmarty->assign('site_media', $this->config->item('site_media'));
    $this->mysmarty->display('smarty.tpl');
  }
}
```

My routes definition looks like the following:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['login'] = 'login';
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

The problem is that I keep getting a 404 when I try to access http://localhost/myapp/login. What did I do wrong? I've checked CI routes docs and cannot spot anything.

Comment: First you need to tell us which CI version you have used ?
Because CI version(3.x), Controller Class name and file name must be first letter capitalize, So it might be issue with capitalization but if your CI version is 3.x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything wrong with this - does it work without the route?
Also, have you set the .htaccess properly (i.e. does http://localhost/myapp/index.php/login work instead)

Comment: Thanks v3 that did it. But why doesn't the default_controller need the index.php?

Comment: By default, if you go to a folder on the web server Apache looks for index.html, index.php, main.php, etc.
So http://localhost/myapp/ is equivalent to http://localhost/myapp/index.php.

Answer (score 2):

Another point to keep in mind, if you have have "enable_query_strings" set to true and aren't using the .htaccess mod_rewrite rules:

In config/config.php:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd';
```

The URL to route your request properly would look like this:

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php?c=login
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not removed your `index.php` from your app using the `.htaccess` file, well thats another ball game on its own. But what you can do is this:

Set a default `controller` that's not the `welcome` file and if you want the welcome file to be your default use the link this way

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/login
```

Remember this way only works when the `index.php` file has not been removed using the `.htaccess` file.

Also open the `apllication/config/config.php` and use this code for the `baseurl`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myapp';
```

That should always do the trick.